# Run script when start the asterisk using service

Tags: system, asterisk, freepbx

I am facing some strange issue to execute script when started the asterisk using "service asterisk start".

I can run script within dialplan using system() app when I started the asterisk using asterisk -vvvvvvvvc but when I start the asterisk using service (service asterisk start), asterisk can not execute the script, getting error like "Can not execute the command".

I have installed the asterisk as asterisk user. setup is done with freepbx installation.

I tried with various option, like changing the script with chown (chown asterisk:asterisk script), chmod 777 script but does not work.

Comment: There is no way answer your question, likly related to your startup script or selinux.

Comment: I have already disabled the selinux, but script is working with normal asterisk start using command ' asterisk -vvvvvvvc' but only does not work with service asterisk start.

Comment: Debug is offtopic here. You have question which can't be answered based on provided info.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS version are you using? 
If it is RHEL / CentOS 7, then you should use "systemctl start asterisk" instead.
If it is RHEL / CentOS 6, then you run the command correctly. Note that this startup script launches an intermediate script safe_asterisk, and the latter, in turn, launches the asterisk itself.

Check /var/log/messages and /var/log/asterisk/full - does anything interesting appear there at the moment of unsuccessful startup?

Could you also share the list of processes (ps -ef | grep asterisk) after you execute this startup script?

Comment: I am using centos 6                                                                          
root      1760     1  0 21:31 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk -U asterisk -G asterisk                                          
asterisk  1763  1760 27 21:31 ?        00:00:04 /usr/sbin/asterisk -f -U asterisk -G asterisk -vvvg -c